# Bandle Template error - Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, view

Good morning, I just started with Symfony and I've been reading errors like mine from different people but I have not finished finding the solution.

I have this folder structure

[Estructura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZih9.png)

I have this error:

> Unable to find template
>   "MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\Symfony\proyectoSymfony\app/Resources/views,
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\Symfony\proyectoSymfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).

And this routing configuration:

```
proyectoSymfony_hola_mundo:
    path: /holamundo
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index}
```

The controller configuration is this code:

```
namespace ProyectoSymfony\HolaMundoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 

class DefaultController extends Controller
{ 
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this>render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig'); 
    }
 }
```

For this line of error looked into: **C:\xampp\htdocs\Exercises\Symfony\proyectoSymfony\app/Resources/views**

I assume that this is the main error but I do not understand why when calling Path holamundo it goes straight to that route.

Comment: `namespace ProyectoSymfony\HolaMundoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('ProyectoSymfonyHolaMundoBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}`

For this line of error looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\Exercises\Symfony\proyectoSymfony\app/Resources/views

I assume that this is the main error but I do not understand why when calling Path holamundo it goes straight to that route.

Comment: Ok, it is done, im sorry

Comment: No problem, you learn how StackOverflow works ;). That seems good to me. are you using the `dev` environement? (url like `app_dev.php/holamundo`

Comment: The Bundle:Controller:file.twig format has pretty much gone away.  Use twig namespaces instead.  Something like: @ProyectoSymfonyHolaMundoBundle/Default/index.html.twig  Use "bin/console debug:twig" to verify that the @ProyectoSymfonyHolaMundoBundle namespace has been properly defined.